# Spring MVC controllers - separating logic from view

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

What is the actual task of controllers in Spring MVC in huge projects?
Should they

1. fetch *use case specific* data, perform view-dependent logic on it and pass it to the view. Big controllers, less presentation logic in JSPs
2. fetch all data that *could be needed* and pass some DTOs with lazy methods to the view, small controllers, big JSPs

Lets say we have an online shop and want to implement the showProduct().
We have quite a lot of display logic that depends on some attributes of some DTOs. For example in JSP we often have some display logic equivalent to this

```
<c:if test="${product.isSameDayPickupSupported && warehouse.stock > 10 && configuration.sameDayPickupEnabled && !soldOut}">
    <div class="sameDayPickup">some HTML goes here</div>
</c:if>
```

In my opinion this is a candidate for pulling this logic out of the JSP and let the controller handle this. At the end we will have this in JSP:

```
<c:if test="${sameDayPickup}">
    <div class="sameDayPickup">some HTML goes here</div>
</c:if>
```

Comment: I agree that option 1 is the better option.  In addition, try to put as much "business" logic in a layer outside the controller as well.  For example, if taking a product "offline" requires three calls to external services put those three into a new layer that the controller calls.

Comment: You should put your `business-logic` in `service` layer. Also, can you re-frame your question a bit more properly in short but precise words.

Comment: Hi @WeareBorg - I re-framed my question and hopefully clarified what my intention is. Thanks

Comment: Big project or small project, task of a controller remains same. You can have your data broken down into multiple parts and can server via controller, but I still don't understand what you want to know. Also, these days, there is not just JSP's, developers use JS, etc for front-end, but again, what has that got to do with controller other then getting data from a controller method is what escapes me.

Comment: Hi, I thought it would be clear with my code example. I am referring to display logic only.

Answer (score 1):

Neither. Your views should be as dumb as possible (for example, you should be able to easily feed them dummy data for development), and your controllers should be a thin layer between the HTTP frontend (HTML/JSON/XML) and a service layer that contains all your business logic. This makes testing both the business logic and the controllers easy and ensures that you can reliably reuse the business logic in multiple variants of your frontend.

In this specific case, the rules that determine whether a certain shipping option is offered definitely belong in the service tier (either a service object or as a method on the domain object, depending on what makes the most sense organizationally). That logic shouldn't be copied into either the controller or the view.